# dynamically create the functions based on the length of the given variable

Tags: javascript

I have a function call “getDocID” which has been defined in some other JS library, for which we can pass a callback function myCallback.

To get the ID’s for more than one we have to chain it, we need to call the function like following, which works fine.

```
function setDocIds(){
    const testValues = ["2980", "2981","2982"];
    const optID = "someValue";
    var myCallback_2 = function (result2){
        var appID = result2.ID;
        document.getElementById("div_2").innerHTML = appID; 
    } 
    var myCallback_1 = function (result1){
        var appID = result1.ID;
        document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML = appID; 
        getDocID(optID, testValues[2], myCallback_2);
    }
    var myCallback = function (result){
        var appID = result.ID;
        document.getElementById("emailtemplate").innerHTML = appID;
        getDocID(optID, testValues[1], myCallback_1);
    }
    getDocID(optID, testValues[0], myCallback);
}
```

Can anyone guide me to optimize the above code and to create the functions dynamically based on the length of the testValues.

Comment: why don't you try recursion ?

Comment: You have `emailtemplate`, then `div_1` then `div_2`. How do you get these values from, say, the index 0, 1, 2? Also not clear to me what you mean by "length of given variable".

Comment: Im not understanding either?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) and scoping.

```js
function getDocID(id, num, callback){
   callback({ID:`optId: ${id} and testVal: ${num}`});
}

function setDocIds() {
  const testValues = ["2980", "2981", '2982'];
  const optID = "someValue";
  testValues.forEach((n, i) => {
    getDocID(optID, n, function(result) {
      const appID = result.ID;
      const id = i === 0 ? "emailtemplate" : `div_${i}`;
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = appID;
    });
  });
}

setDocIds();
```

```html
<div id="emailtemplate"></div>
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_2"></div>
```

Comment: You should fix the "nice" quotes that will result in syntax errors.

Comment: @ChrisG I noticed that when I was making a working example. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is the same - the OP's code chains the calls so the result of a previous call to `getDocID` is used in the next one.

Comment: @PeterHull No it doesn't.

Comment: No values are passed from one callback to another, so in my opinion there could be no need to for chain callbacks. Just need to wait to see what OP says.

Comment: Yes you are both right. getDocID might have side-effects though. I agree with @kemicofa, the OP should comment on this.

Comment: actually logically chaining is not required, but due to some unknown issues in the getDocID function which is defined in some other library, does not allow me to get the values without chaining, if I don't use chaining it overrides the last callback and first, two callbacks values do not show in the output.

Comment: @anuja can you show the contents of the getDocID funciton?

Comment: @kemicofa , the appDocID is the getApprovedDocument function found in veeva library, https://www.veeva.com/veeva-library-3-2-js/